# couldn't instantiate class MyTaskListener for task listener

Tags: java, activiti

I have created a bpmn process which contains a timer task. I want to execute line of code at the time of completion of timer task. I have write a task listener for this and put the jar into tomcat/lib folder but it is showing exception "couldn't instantiate class MyTaskListener". Please give some suggestion. Thanks in advance

Comment: give us code we can work with

Comment: Our *crystal ball* is bit blurry right now. It demands something to work with.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just one line of code you need to execute, then why don't you use the ScriptTaskListener (org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.listener.ScriptTaskListener)?

This is documented here: http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#taskListeners

The beauty of the script task listener is that it acts just like a script task (meaning, you can use groovy or javascript) and doesnt require you register any extra classes. Now, obviously if you have a lot of code to run, you are better off with classes, but, if you have only a single line of ode (as you indicate in your post) then ScriptTaskListener is ideal.

Hope this helps,
Greg

Comment: Thanks for reply... i have read the document. I want to update another database when timer task get completed so i am not using ScriptTaskListener.

Comment: Oh, so updating an external database is certainly more than one line of code, you should create either a bean to handle the crud operations, you can then use expressions to handle crud. Alternatively, a listener class is the way to go.

Comment: I created a listener class for this. Now how to register bean for listener and where to define this bean.